# Using YouTube's API to Render Preview

Tags: api, youtube, preview

I'm working on a personal project and need to render a preview of a Youtube video by the URL similar to how Facebook pulls the preview thumbnail and title/description.

Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction; does the API allow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the YouTube V3 API, the video resource has a `snippet` property with the information you would need to do this. The `snippet.thumbnails` property is an object that provides image URLs in various sizes. The `snippet.title` property provides the title and the `snippet.description` property provides the description.

A sample request would be:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet&id=VIDEO-ID&key=YOUR-API-KEY`

For more information, see YouTube's API documentation regarding the [video object](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos).

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated. Additionally, apparently thumbnails are pretty readily available by using the video ID as such:

http://img.youtube.com/vi/<ID>/0.jpg

Will need the `snippet.title` and `snippet.description` calls though. Thank you sir.